# Use navigation push to new view only Navigation Title change

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I create a UserProfile TableView and use below code push to new view

```
CollectionIndexViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@"xxxxxxxxxxx"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

[image]

Usually It work good.But sometime when I want to push new view, I found only the Navigation Title change. But the content don't change. seem block.
[image]

But When I press home button and restore app again.The Content View change to new View:I have no idea what is going on.What wrong with my code. Anyone known why please help me.Thanks

[image]

Comment: You did something strange to set blank image.Codes in second vc will help.

Comment: Share some code. Otherwise it will be a blind guess.